# Do you use 30 day trial servers to do development work?

Tags: trial

I know this is an odd question but I need to ask it to get information to present to a client. Their lead network admin wants me to work on 30 day trial servers like Sharepoint & SQL Server to develop projects for their clients. While I will do as they ask, I'm not convinced this is the best way to go about developing software or troubleshooting previously developed software. To be honest, I've never worked on custom development for any server/software using a trial version.

What arguements are there for and against working on trial software/servers?

Comment: Well, the trial versions are there for me to test ideas, develop customizations to go into the client's servers. I do agree with you, but I need a stronger arguement.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use SharePoint Services and SQL Express for development? The Windows server license will set you back either way. But if you are looking for a personal copy you can get Windows Home Server for about $100. (I am referring to the original based on Windows 2003 server not the new version they are developing.)

Comment: The clients use Sharepoint. Most of these clients are fairly large companies. It's not feasible to change their software direction.

Comment: I never asid to change their software.  Most everything on MOSS is the same as SharePoint Services and SharePoint doesn't really care what database version you install against.  SharePoint services and SQLExpress are both free. WHS is windows 2003 server with a bunch of stuff for home use (which can be ignored.)

Answer (score 4):

**Pro:** It enables you to mock up a concept and see if it seems like the development path will be easy before you shell out large amounts of money for the real deal.

**Cons:** It could trap you in a vicious cycle of wiping your virtual machine and re-installing the OS, the trial version, and your product (you do use source control, correct?) if they are hoping that this will alleviate the need for ever paying for the real product.

**Suggestion:** If you don't mind unsolicited advice, then I would determine *why* the lead admin wants to use the trial versions -- and then go from there.  Until you know the reasons you cannot respond to them.

If they are doing it for the pro reason, then determine if you feel comfortable working with the possibility of switching technologies 30 days into your build. (Can you do it efficiently?)

If they are doing it to avoid spending money, present some of the alternate open source / free options that you are comfortable developing with. If they will not change their *[modus operandi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_operandi)* at that point, then do what is necessary, knowing what you will be walking away from / getting in to.

(And if you don't mind one more bit of unsolicited advice -- if they are doing it for the con reason and will not change **WALK AWAY**)

Comment: Thanks Sean
Mostly, I think they are doing it to save money, however they may not feel so comfortable doing that when they find out that I will bill them for the time to reinstall all of this software every 30 days onto their network for my use.

Comment: Desirea -- I would let them know that in advance. Giving them the benefit of the doubt, if they just are trying to save some money and not to cheat you or Microsoft out of anything, then when you show them the *expected* cost over the length of development time to do it their way, versus the *known* cost of buying another licence for SQL server and Sharepoint, you should be able to help them see the benefit of doing it your way.

Comment: You should also look at the licences and agreements that comes with your software. Some software doesn't allow any "commercial" developpement with trials and/or educationnal versions. This could lead to some serious lawsuit and ending up paying far more than actually buying the software.

Comment: @Frank; very good point!

Comment: Thanks Sean & Frank 
I definitely will let them know that it will cost them extra for setup and any other work related to resetting up and tearing down. 

Frank, most of the custom development is for Sharepoint which is actually covered by Sharepoint.

Answer (score 3):

Point them at **[BizSpark](http://www.microsoft.com/bizSpark/Startup/Signup.aspx)**. Microsoft is begging people to use their stuff. A hunny will get you everything on the map for 3 years or until you start making money.

Oh, to answer your question: If I need to get funding for technology not present in the infrastructure or to do a proof of concept I would not think twice about using evals. That is what they are for. I would be evaluating the suitability of the product for use with my designs. Seems easy to me. Maybe I am just, hold on, i have to give my parrot a cracker... ;-)

Comment: Or... get them to spring for an MSDN subscription. That is exactly what it is for and no timebombs

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the ethical arguments, there are practical ones:

What are you supposed to do if development overruns? Start reinstalling everything, wasting several days doing so?

Additionally, if the client is so strapped for cash that they want to do this, how can you be certain they will pay you (either due to cash flow problems, or simply because of their shady ethics)?

Comment: Well, they aren't strapped for cash, their clients are paying them double to triple what I charge them for my services. I believe that perhaps the network admin does not want to go to the trouble of downloading and setting up these servers/software products.

Comment: Just like Oded I would worry about me getting paid by such a client...

Comment: Heard of infrastructure as code? Every single one of our applications automatically installs and configure itself. If your dev work gets disrupted because you need to "start reinstalling everything wasting several days doing so", you got bigger problems.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that that kind of use is a violation of license terms. Trial editions of servers are for evaluating a product. And if you are in fact creating a product, then you have gone way beyond evaluation.

I would never work under such terms. If you are developing a concrete product, get proper licenses for the development tools. I know that the developer edition of SQL server is not hugely expensive (compared to a version licensed for production use), so I would imagine that the same counts for Sharepoint.

And then there is of course, as already mentioned, what do you do when the trail period expires?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't mind doing this so long as the job is shorter than 30 days.  Make sure your work contract they're paying for the time worked and not specific deliverables, because your deliverables are time-bombed.

Also be prepared to walk away.  If this company doesn't have resources to get the right software, you don't want to be there longer than 30 days anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft provides several pre-built virtual machines, that contains full stacks.
(Server 2008/Sql 2008/Sharepoin)   (Server 2003/Sql/Project Server) etc. 
They are time bombed, but often (not always) Microsoft will provide a new image after the time out.

The benefit of using these images is that they are already configured and good to go.
As an example here is a beta of sharepoint 2010 (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0c51819b-3d40-435c-a103-a5481fe0a0d2&displaylang=en).

If the project has a quick timeline, it provides the developers access to the configured stack  right away, with no ramp up time of building new virtual machines.

Esp when working on beta/early release software this is great.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL Server evaluation's [download page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/bb851664.aspx) mentions that the evaluation license is good for 180 days, and specifically advertises it as a tool you can use for mission-critical applications.  This tells me MS is fine with your using it for development work.

To answer a question with more questions:

1. How long does this project run?
2. What phase of the effort are you in now?
3. Is this an internal/proof-of-concept project, or something that your customer(s) will be using for a long time?

If you are going to need to use SQL Server for Operations & Maintenance support months past the initial evaluation period, you ought to get a license for the full version of it.  And also consider what your customers are using so that you can reproduce any bugs that come back from them.

I don't think it's ethical to continually renew evaluation licenses to have a longer evaluation period.  Companies call them "evaluations" as a try-before-you-buy, not a keep-trying-without-buying.

Comment: Microsoft states clearly that the evaluation version of SQL Server is forbidden for production use.

Comment: I didn't see that in their agreement when I first answered the question, but it sounds like the OP was using it for proof-of-concept work, not for production.  See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_life_cycle#Deployment_and_maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what others are seeing as unethical here. If the project is short enough to be completed within the 30 day trial, I don't see any issues. I think that's a great use of trials - if they can't handle a clients applications then they aren't a good option and you can use something else.

I think others here have given some good advice regarding the longer than 30 days projects and some good contract ideas.

Comment: I think people consider unethical periodically reinstalling all the tools just to keep the mission going longer.

Comment: @Andrei - I guess I assumed he would be doing dev work on clients systems and they want to use 30 day trials for the dev work. I think it's cheesy to do dev work on constant 30 day trials and then refreshing just to reload where you left off and continuing.

Answer (score 0):

How in-house do the servers have to be?  Would a hosted solution work for them?  (Dreamhost, Amazon Web Services, whatever)?  Some hosting systems provide pretty complex machine images (lots of stuff pre-installed--definitely AWS, presumably most others), decreasing setup time/effort.  I *think* those come with licenses, though I don't honestly know.  Plus, in at least some cases, you (they) only pay for what you (they) use.

Obviously no good if the physical machine needs to be in-house, or if things are otherwise super-sensitive.